# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.. for email functionality using asp.net

Tags: smtpclient

While working on email functionality using asp.net, I found the following error :

Unknown error occurred when sending email: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure..    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)

After analysis on the above issue I found the solution as mentioned below :

Setting the SMTPEnableSsl property of the SmtpClient class to false resolved the issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: You should write your answer as an answer to your own question and then, after a time set by stack overflow, mark it as answer. Then Stackoverflow will pick up your answer as an answer. FWIW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysis on the above issue I found the solution as mentioned below :

Setting the SMTPEnableSsl property of the SmtpClient class to false resolved the issue.

Comment: This would not fly if the Server requires SSL connections. Think of a scenario when you dont administrate the SMTP server